# How can I use _lodash to work on fields inside an array backing them up and restoring them?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to do some array manipulation and would like to have someone
tell me if _lodash is somthing that I could use for this. What I have
is an array called `result` that contains the following:

```
var result = 
[
{"referenceId":20,"callerId":1, "location":2},
{"referenceId":21,"callerId":1, "location":3}
]
```

I would like to create a backup of this array that looks like this:

```
var resultBackup =
[
{"location":2},
{"location":3}
]
```

My users may change the data such that the array looks like this:

```
var result = 
[
{"referenceId":20,"callerId":1, "location":999},
{"referenceId":21,"callerId":1, "location":123}
]
```

I need to be able to update my original array with just the location field from the data in the backup array and
restore it to:

```
var result = 
[
{"referenceId":20,"callerId":1, "location":2},
{"referenceId":21,"callerId":1, "location":3}
]
```

Is something like this possible with _lodash ?

Comment: Yes it is. It's also easy to do without any library. (Note: Yes/no questions are usually not good Stack Overflow questions)

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks for your advice. I changed the title of my question. Hope someone can give me an example either with or without _lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the backup array, you can use [`_.map`](http://lodash.com/docs#map) or the native [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the original objects to a new object with just one property:

```
var resultBackup = _.map(result, function(e) { // or result.map(function(e) {
    return {location: e.location};
});
```

Then to restore the values, you want to "merge" the result object with the backup object. Lo-Dash provides [`_.assign`](http://lodash.com/docs#assign) for that:

```
_.forEach(result, function(e, index) {
    _.assign(e, resultBackup[index]);
});
```

Or without a library:

```
result.forEach(function(e, index) {
    var backup = resultBackup[index];
    for (var prop in backup) {
        e[prop] = backup[prop];
    }
});
```